# Wordpress Custom Post Type Children Template

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, hierarchical

I have created a hierarchical custom post type in wordpress called "films." It is hierarchical so it can have children elements.

When a "film" is clicked, wordpress automatically uses the template called 'single-films.php'. That is great, but I wish to use a different template when one of the film's children pages is clicked. For instance, a child of a film might be "press." When that film's press link is clicked, I want it to use a different template than single-films.php.

I was hoping there is some way I can use a template like single-children-films.php. Any ideas how I can change a hierarchical custom post type's  children template?

Comment: or, another way of handling it is to add conditional logic to the single-films.php saying if this post is a parent, do this...if this post is a child, do this....But I'm unsure of the code to do that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, from within `single-films.php` you filter based on the parent post you should have little issue with this. For example:

```
if( $post->post_parent != 0 ) {
    // not top level
} else {
    // top level page
}
```

If you need to know how deep the page is, that's a different matter, but that's also doable (unfortunately it means you need to query the database though).